# Eclipse maven project oscreating just sources.jar instead of just .jar in target folder

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-8, eclipse-rcp

I tried running mvn install and the target folder is updated just with one jar file that has project-name-**sources**.jar files ...

1.Tried to update the project but no luck

When I use the project-name-sources.jar in other project dependencies, I am getting different package icons
[Incorrect icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjPWm.png)

Instead of the icons
[Correct icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TcYy.png)

I am using eclipse RCP

My pom just has maven release plugin

Comment: The souce-package is not intended for consumption on the classpath more for convenience in the IDE...

Comment: Right.. the main issue is why the mvn install is creating just source.jar instead of main jar file

Comment: Than the project is wrong configured..weird...